# Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type.... what am I doing wrong?

Tags: c#, json, rest, dotnet-httpclient

I'm learning how to make API calls and keep getting issues (deserializing JSON) with my response.

I've checked a number of solutions for the same issue but with no luck.

Is there anything with the way I've set this up?

Note: I'm wanting to play around with the Twitter API (hence the Tweets and Tweet classes) but I'm testing out my Get requests on a simple dummy data.

```
    public class HomeController : Controller
{
    Tweets model = null;
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
        var task =
            client.GetAsync(
            "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/")
            .ContinueWith((taskwithresponse) =>
                {
                    var response = taskwithresponse.Result;
                    var readtask = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Tweets>();
                    readtask.Wait();
                    model = readtask.Result;
                });
        task.Wait();
        return View(model.results);
    }
}

    public class Tweets
{
    public Tweet[] results;
}
public class Tweet
{
    [JsonProperty("body")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("title")]
    public string TweetText { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Do you get an exception? Is the response empty? What's the problem?

Comment: show example json string. then we can help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `List<Tweet>` as model.

```
public ActionResult Index2()
{
    List<Tweet> model = null;
    var client = new HttpClient();
    client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
    var task =
        client.GetAsync(
        "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/")
        .ContinueWith((taskwithresponse) =>
        {
            var response = taskwithresponse.Result;
            var readtask = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<Tweet>>();
            readtask.Wait();
            model = readtask.Result;
        });
    task.Wait();
    return View(model);
}
```